Why does rendering of Rmd file with datatable fails when bslib is used on shinyapps.io?
This question might be a bug report but I would appreciate a hint (and potential solution) before filing one at the right place.
I maintain a Shiny app hosted on shinyapps.io which allows the user to generate HTML reports based on Rmd templates. The rendering started to fail after a recent update with a pandoc error indicating an out of memory condition (pandoc document conversion failed with error 137).
I tracked the error down to be caused by a combination of shinyapps.io, bslib and DT used in an Rmd file (minimal reproducible example below).
I would be happy if someone could hint at a possible solution or provide advice for the right place to file a bug report (if it is a bug).
The error only occurs when the app is deployed to shinyapps.io using bslib::page_fluid. When running the app locally, the Rmd rendering works. Hence, I suspect that the pandoc version used at shinyapps.io is the problem but I can not properly test this.
You can find the offending App at https://jali.shinyapps.io/TestApp/. However, pressing the download button will only reproduce the error. I deployed it using the following two files, app.R
ui  <- bslib::page_fluid(
#ui  <- shiny::fluidPage(
  shiny::downloadButton(outputId = "rmd", label = "Render Rmd")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$rmd <- shiny::downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {"Report.html"},
    content = function(file) {
      rmarkdown::render(
        input = "template.Rmd",
        output_file = file,
        output_format = rmarkdown::html_document()
      )
    }
  )
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

and template.Rmd
```{r DT, echo=FALSE, comment=NA}
  DT::datatable(data = data.frame("Test"=1:3))
```{}

(Sorry for the extra brackets {} in template.Rmd, didn't know how to format correctly.)
When deploying this app using shiny::fluidPage (see outcommented line in app.R) everything works at shinyapps.io. Also, when printing the test dataframe (not using DT), everything is ok.
Below is the log info from shinyapps.io upon startup and once the download button is clicked to start rendering.

024-06-14T20:45:54.790590+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: Running on host:
9736844199c4 2024-06-14T20:45:54.795171+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]:
Running as user: uid=10001(shiny) gid=10001(shiny) groups=10001(shiny)
2024-06-14T20:45:54.799620+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: Connect version:
2024.05.0 2024-06-14T20:45:54.804055+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: LANG: C.UTF-8 2024-06-14T20:45:54.808429+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: Working
directory: /srv/connect/apps/TestApp 2024-06-14T20:45:54.812713+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]: Using R 4.3.1 2024-06-14T20:45:54.816956+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]: R.home(): /opt/R/4.3.1/lib/R
2024-06-14T20:45:54.821404+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: Content will use
current R environment 2024-06-14T20:45:54.825801+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]: R_LIBS: (unset) 2024-06-14T20:45:54.830125+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]: .libPaths(): /usr/lib/R,
/opt/R/4.3.1/lib/R/library 2024-06-14T20:45:54.834697+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]: shiny version: 1.8.1.1
2024-06-14T20:45:54.839110+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: httpuv version:
1.6.15 2024-06-14T20:45:54.843469+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: rmarkdown version: 2.26 2024-06-14T20:45:54.847983+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]:
knitr version: 1.46 2024-06-14T20:45:54.852635+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]: jsonlite version: 1.8.8
2024-06-14T20:45:54.857314+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: RJSONIO version:
(none) 2024-06-14T20:45:54.861731+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: htmltools
version: 0.5.8.1 2024-06-14T20:45:54.866345+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]:
reticulate version: (none) 2024-06-14T20:45:54.871717+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.16
2024-06-14T20:45:54.876316+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]:
2024-06-14T20:45:54.880830+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: Starting R with
process ID: '32' 2024-06-14T20:45:54.885259+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]:
Shiny application starting ... 2024-06-14T20:45:54.889983+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]:  2024-06-14T20:45:54.894687+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:43517
2024-06-14T21:01:32.883063+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: Container event
from container-9706893: stop 2024-06-16T07:26:25.472835+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]: Container event from container-9706893: start
2024-06-16T07:26:29.472831+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: Running on host:
c279b780ae28 2024-06-16T07:26:29.477208+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]:
Running as user: uid=10001(shiny) gid=10001(shiny) groups=10001(shiny)
2024-06-16T07:26:29.481404+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: Connect version:
2024.05.0 2024-06-16T07:26:29.485300+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: LANG: C.UTF-8 2024-06-16T07:26:29.489434+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: Working
directory: /srv/connect/apps/TestApp 2024-06-16T07:26:29.493338+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]: Using R 4.3.1 2024-06-16T07:26:29.497530+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]: R.home(): /opt/R/4.3.1/lib/R
2024-06-16T07:26:29.501755+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: Content will use
current R environment 2024-06-16T07:26:29.505732+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]: R_LIBS: (unset) 2024-06-16T07:26:29.509640+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]: .libPaths(): /usr/lib/R,
/opt/R/4.3.1/lib/R/library 2024-06-16T07:26:29.513501+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]: shiny version: 1.8.1.1
2024-06-16T07:26:29.517338+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: httpuv version:
1.6.15 2024-06-16T07:26:29.521427+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: rmarkdown version: 2.26 2024-06-16T07:26:29.525431+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]:
knitr version: 1.46 2024-06-16T07:26:29.529464+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]: jsonlite version: 1.8.8
2024-06-16T07:26:29.533536+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: RJSONIO version:
(none) 2024-06-16T07:26:29.537638+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: htmltools
version: 0.5.8.1 2024-06-16T07:26:29.541555+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]:
reticulate version: (none) 2024-06-16T07:26:29.545694+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.16
2024-06-16T07:26:29.549708+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]:
2024-06-16T07:26:29.553988+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: Starting R with
process ID: '31' 2024-06-16T07:26:29.558113+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]:
Shiny application starting ... 2024-06-16T07:26:29.562294+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]:  2024-06-16T07:26:29.566279+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:44067 [upon click
on download button] 2024-06-16T07:29:09.482079+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]: processing file: template.Rmd
2024-06-16T07:29:09.486251+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: 1/1 [DT]
2024-06-16T07:29:09.490345+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: output file:
template.knit.md 2024-06-16T07:29:09.494372+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]:
2024-06-16T07:29:09.498706+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]:
/opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.16/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS template.knit.md
--to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output
/tmp/RtmpSCGqEp/file1f4028edb.html --lua-filter
/usr/lib/R/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter
/usr/lib/R/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --self-contained
--variable bs3=TRUE --section-divs --template /usr/lib/R/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --no-highlight --variable
highlightjs=1 --variable theme=bootstrap --mathjax --variable
'mathjax-url=https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'
--include-in-header /tmp/RtmpSCGqEp/rmarkdown-str1f3159e9ff.html  2024-06-16T07:29:09.503288+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: [WARNING] This
document format requires a nonempty  element.
2024-06-16T07:29:09.507894+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]:   Defaulting to
'template.knit' as the title. 2024-06-16T07:29:09.511964+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]:   To specify a title, use 'title' in metadata or
--metadata title="...". 2024-06-16T07:29:12.472491+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: Killed 2024-06-16T07:29:12.477204+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]: Warning: Error in : pandoc document conversion
failed with error 137 2024-06-16T07:29:12.481571+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]:   15: 
2024-06-16T07:29:12.486026+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]:   13: fn
2024-06-16T07:29:12.490634+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]:    8: retry
2024-06-16T07:29:12.495090+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]:    7:
connect$retryingStartServer 2024-06-16T07:29:12.499435+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]:    6: eval 2024-06-16T07:29:12.503597+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]:    5: eval 2024-06-16T07:29:12.508141+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]:    4: eval 2024-06-16T07:29:12.512594+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]:    3: eval 2024-06-16T07:29:12.516469+00:00
shinyapps[12177969]:    2: eval.parent
2024-06-16T07:29:12.520489+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]:    1: local
2024-06-16T07:29:12.524754+00:00 shinyapps[12177969]: Container event
from container-9706893: oom (out of memory)

I deployed TestApp2 which is working as expected because I substituted bslib::page_fluid against shiny::fluidPage.

2024-06-16T07:39:52.344409+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]: Container event
from container-9712977: start 2024-06-16T07:39:57.254173+00:00
shinyapps[12189076]: Running on host: 96c659ddd69e
2024-06-16T07:39:57.258816+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]: Running as user:
uid=10001(shiny) gid=10001(shiny) groups=10001(shiny)
2024-06-16T07:39:57.262442+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]: Connect version:
2024.05.0 2024-06-16T07:39:57.266250+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]: LANG: C.UTF-8 2024-06-16T07:39:57.269916+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]: Working
directory: /srv/connect/apps/TestApp2 2024-06-16T07:39:57.273494+00:00
shinyapps[12189076]: Using R 4.3.1 2024-06-16T07:39:57.276921+00:00
shinyapps[12189076]: R.home(): /opt/R/4.3.1/lib/R
2024-06-16T07:39:57.280807+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]: Content will use
current R environment 2024-06-16T07:39:57.284477+00:00
shinyapps[12189076]: R_LIBS: (unset) 2024-06-16T07:39:57.288096+00:00
shinyapps[12189076]: .libPaths(): /usr/lib/R,
/opt/R/4.3.1/lib/R/library 2024-06-16T07:39:57.291570+00:00
shinyapps[12189076]: shiny version: 1.8.1.1
2024-06-16T07:39:57.294988+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]: httpuv version:
1.6.15 2024-06-16T07:39:57.299979+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]: rmarkdown version: 2.26 2024-06-16T07:39:57.303475+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]:
knitr version: 1.46 2024-06-16T07:39:57.306804+00:00
shinyapps[12189076]: jsonlite version: 1.8.8
2024-06-16T07:39:57.310129+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]: RJSONIO version:
(none) 2024-06-16T07:39:57.313536+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]: htmltools
version: 0.5.8.1 2024-06-16T07:39:57.316960+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]:
reticulate version: (none) 2024-06-16T07:39:57.320797+00:00
shinyapps[12189076]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.16
2024-06-16T07:39:57.324269+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]:
2024-06-16T07:39:57.327775+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]: Starting R with
process ID: '31' 2024-06-16T07:39:57.331411+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]:
Shiny application starting ... 2024-06-16T07:39:57.334956+00:00
shinyapps[12189076]:  2024-06-16T07:39:57.338183+00:00
shinyapps[12189076]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:36991 [upon click
on download button] 2024-06-16T07:40:44.260826+00:00
shinyapps[12189076]: processing file: template.Rmd
2024-06-16T07:40:45.254009+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]: 1/1 [DT]
2024-06-16T07:40:45.258617+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]: output file:
template.knit.md 2024-06-16T07:40:45.262315+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]:
2024-06-16T07:40:45.265930+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]:
/opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.16/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS template.knit.md
--to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output
/tmp/RtmpTYRsUo/file1f6a4bf6bf.html --lua-filter
/usr/lib/R/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter
/usr/lib/R/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --self-contained
--variable bs3=TRUE --section-divs --template /usr/lib/R/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --no-highlight --variable
highlightjs=1 --variable theme=bootstrap --mathjax --variable
'mathjax-url=https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'
--include-in-header /tmp/RtmpTYRsUo/rmarkdown-str1f4fd99153.html  2024-06-16T07:40:45.269613+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]: [WARNING] This
document format requires a nonempty  element.
2024-06-16T07:40:45.273323+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]:   Defaulting to
'template.knit' as the title. 2024-06-16T07:40:45.276770+00:00
shinyapps[12189076]:   To specify a title, use 'title' in metadata or
--metadata title="...". 2024-06-16T07:40:45.280638+00:00 shinyapps[12189076]:  2024-06-16T07:40:45.284455+00:00
shinyapps[12189076]: Output created:
/tmp/RtmpTYRsUo/file1f6a4bf6bf.html

Finally the sessionInfo() output of my local machine where both App versions work as expected, generating a HTML report with a DT table.

R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)
Matrix products: default
locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.utf8
LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.utf8    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.utf8 [4]
LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.utf8
time zone: Europe/Berlin tzcode source: internal
attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
datasets  methods   base
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] digest_0.6.35
later_1.3.2       R6_2.5.1          httpuv_1.6.15     fastmap_1.1.1
xfun_0.43          [7] magrittr_2.0.3    cachem_1.0.8
shiny_1.8.1.1     knitr_1.46        htmltools_0.5.8.1 rmarkdown_2.26
[13] lifecycle_1.0.4   promises_1.3.0    cli_3.6.2
askpass_1.2.0     openssl_2.1.2     xtable_1.8-4      [19] sass_0.4.9
rsconnect_1.2.2   jquerylib_0.1.4   compiler_4.3.1
rstudioapi_0.16.0 tools_4.3.1       [25] curl_5.2.1
evaluate_0.23     mime_0.12         bslib_0.7.0       Rcpp_1.0.12
rlang_1.1.3       [31] jsonlite_1.8.8


Are there any useful logs available from the shinyapps.io logs menu?

And can you provide any information about package versions, OS, R version etc that you’re using both locally and on shinyapps.io?

@Arthur I attached shinyapps.io logs for both, the failing and the working version.

@Limey I added my local sessionInfo.

I can't see anything useful in the logs.  Is it possible that the DT download button only works in a Shiny app with a server back end?  When you display the DT table in .Rmd, it is acting as a static .html and has no access to Shiny.  I would try displaying the DT in Shiny with DTOutput and renderDT.

@Arthur In the app I actually try to fix, different generated DT objects are displayed and rendered correctly in the live app. The users have the option to download these DT objects in Rmd based report files and this is where pandoc returns the oom error.

As indicated in the question above: the error only occurs when all of the following conditions are met:

deployed on shinyapps.io (locally all combinations work)
using bslib::page_fluid (all combinations work with shiny::fluidPage)
having a DT object in the Rmd template (without DT all combinations work)

The error could be i.m.o. in the pandoc version used at shinyapps.io, causing a conflict when rendering the DT, only incase that bslib 'overwrites' something essential.

I can't track this further down unfortunately but would hope that someone experienced with pandoc, could reproduce the error locally using pandoc 2.16 as on shinyapps.io.

I had the exact same problem (using bslib::page_fillable with a RMD knitted with an actionButton and including a datatable that was working fine locally but was killed on shinyapps.io). Thanks to this post I fixed it changing page_fillable by fluidPage but it's not as satisfying. I think it would be useful if you could post an issue on Github, it will probably happen to other people!
